# Styling and layout help in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, stylesheet

I am pretty new to react native and I am trying to create a layout for my home page in react native but I am unable to achieve my final design. Here are the problems that I am facing with

1- The image does not load in the container

2- I cannot get the shadow right for the small containers

3- The total alignment seems to be old when matched with the final output.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,
           Text,
           View ,
           Image,
           ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import LocalImage from './components/localimage';

export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={[styles.boxContainer,styles.boxOne]}>
        <Text>Header</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={[styles.boxContainer,styles.boxTwo]}>
      <View style = {styles.headerImage}>
        <Image source ={{uri 
   :'https://s3.amazonaws.com/celebrasain2018/pic.jpg'}}/>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={[styles.boxContainer,styles.boxThree]}>
      <View style={[styles.boxHead]}>
          <View style={styles.innerBoxone}>
            <View style={styles.iBoxone} ><Text>box 1</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.iBoxTwo}><Text>box 2</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.iBoxThree}><Text>box 3</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.iBoxFour}><Text>box 4</Text></View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.innerBoxTwo}>
            <View style={styles.kBoxOne} ><Text>second box 1</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.kBoxTwo}><Text>second box 2</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.kBoxThree}><Text>second box 3</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.kBoxFour}><Text>second box 4</Text></View>
          </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
    );
   }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
flexDirection:'column'
},
boxContainer:{
flex:1,
alignItems:'center',
justifyContent:'center'
},
boxOne:{
flex:1,
backgroundColor :'#FFEEE4'
},
boxTwo:{
flex:3,
backgroundColor :'#F9F9F9',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
marginLeft :10,
marginRight:10
},
headerImage:{
width: 50,
height: 50
},
boxThree:{
flex:6,
backgroundColor :'#F9F9F9',
marginLeft: 10,
marginRight: 10,
marginTop: 10,
marginBottom: 10
},
boxHead:{
flex :1,
flexDirection :'row'
},
innerBoxone:{
flex:1,
backgroundColor :'#F9F9F9',
justifyContent: 'space-around',
alignItems: 'stretch',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
marginRight: 5
},
innerBoxTwo:{
flex:1,
backgroundColor :'#F9F9F9',
justifyContent: 'space-around',
alignItems: 'stretch',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
marginLeft: 5
},
iBoxone:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#ddd',
borderBottomWidth:0 ,
padding:32,
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOffset:{width: 0, height: 2},
elevation: 1,
shadowOpacity: 0.8,
shadowRadius: 2
},
iBoxTwo:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
iBoxThree:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
iBoxFour:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
kBoxOne:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
kBoxTwo:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
kBoxThree:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
},
kBoxFour:{
backgroundColor :'#FFF',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius:20,
borderColor:'#e5e6e8',
padding:32
}
});
```

[image: This is what I am getting from the above code.You can see the image is not getting loaded and alignment is completely off] [image: This is the final output that I am looking for]

Any help would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add height and width for the image to appear. Currently you have added height and width for the `View` instead of the `Image`

Comment: @Ayush ..Thank you .I was able to get the image loaded in the right dimension when apply the style to image rather the container .

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of styling the container of the image, style the image itself with `height`, `width`, `borderRadius` etc. Once done with the image, adjust its container `View`.And you might want to add some more margin between the header and the first content.
2. I think what you need is `borderRadius` and `borderWidth` for the small containers according to your design, and not shadow.
3. You do not need to create separate style object for each box you have, instead create `flatlist`, a method to loop and generate multiple boxes from a single one, and style them in groups using `flexbox` features. You can have all the styling for the boxes in one style object, and if you want to apply some additional style to one of the box you can supply and array of styles to same object like this

Comment: ..Thanks for the information.I was able to implement your first two points and was able to get what I wanted but I am still having a hard time with the small containers. Would it be possible to show a sample snippet using flastlist to generate multiple boxes as I havent figured a way to use that for this purpose.